# How to get latest deployed date and time of a particular application in java class deployed in IBM Web sphere application server

Tags: websphere-8

How to get latest deployed date and time of a particular application in java class deployed in IBM WebSphere application server?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a single server, you could look at the filesystem timestamp of the application binary in the directory /profiles//installedApps/, although if you've done any application or module updates that timestamp would likely reflect that and not the original install info.   If you have the server logs archived, you could sift through them to find the INFO log from when the application was installed.